# Return value from thread (runnable)

Tags: android, dao, runnable, android-room

I'm working with Room to persist data, the new AAC for persisting data, and I work on an app where the Todo app provided in the [Google's github repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) serves as our blueprint.
I've been trying to get a value returned by a transaction performed on an entity. I used a global variable `mCategories` to retrieve and store the data returned but I keep on having a null object being returned.

Here's my code:

```
 public interface LoadDataListener<T>
{
    void onReadTransactionCompleted(T arg);
}

private void readTransaction(final LoadDataListener<List<Category>> loadDataListener, final boolean onlyClassic)
{
    Runnable readRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<Category> categories;
            if (!onlyClassic)
                categories = mCategoryDAO.loadAllSellingCategories();
            else
                categories = mCategoryDAO.loadAllClassicCategories();

            LOGD(TAG, "Category size: "+ categories.size());
            // The log above reads a value > 0
            loadDataListener.onReadTransactionCompleted(categories);
        }
    };

    mAppExecutors.diskIO().execute(readRunnable);
}

private List<Category> getSanitizedAndPersistedCategories(boolean onlyClassic) {
    readTransaction(new LoadDataListener<List<Category>>() {
        @Override
        public void onReadTransactionCompleted(List<Category> arg) {
            mCategories = arg;
            LOGD(TAG, "sanitizeCategoriesList size before: " + mCategories);
            // The log above reads a value > 0

        }
    }, onlyClassic);

    LOGD(TAG, "sanitizeCategoriesList size after: " + mCategories);
    // The log above reads null
    return sanitizeCategoriesList(mCategories);
}
```

What am I missing here ??

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have **2 threads** here.
When you call `readTransaction()` and then `mAppExecutors.diskIO().execute(readRunnable)`, method `readTransaction()` returns immediately and calls `LOGD(TAG, "sanitizeCategoriesList size after: " + mCategories);`, which as expected prints `null`. In the meantime, asynchronously on second thread, `run()` is executed, invoking at the end`onReadTransactionCompleted()` and finally setting `mCategories` value.

So you can only rely on `mCategories` after `onReadTransactionCompleted()` was invoked.

If you are using `mCategories` for UI related stuff, you might wanna consider using [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and moving your code from `run()` to `doInBackground()` and code from `onReadTransactionCompleted()` to `onPostExecute()`